# react app on heroku doesn't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, redux

I got an app working fine with localhost but it doesn't start in my heruko instance.
Here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "innova-client",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config build/webpack.development.js",
    "watch-build": "webpack --progress --watch --config build/webpack.development.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^2.7.5",
    "@types/jest": "^18.1.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.54",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.14",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.23",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.37",
    "@types/react-router": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^4.0.42",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^15.4.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^2.6.34",
    "@types/redux-persist": "^4.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.1",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "jest-cli": "^19.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.6",
    "ts-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.8.2",
    "redux-persist": "^4.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the code of webpack.development.js :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.tsx'
    ],

    output: {
        filename: '../webapp/public/javascripts/app.js',
    },

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'}
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader'}
        ]
    }
};
```

And there is the code of webpack.standalone.js :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',

    output: {
        path: 'public',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'}
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader'}
        ]
    },

    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: 'public/',
        port: 3000
    }
};
```

I can run npm install and then npm start. My app starts fine.

Now Id' like to deploy my app on heroku, so I've created a git repository and I ignored the "node_modules" directory.
When going to the url generated by Heroku, I got the message "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

When entering `heroku logs` I got these messages :

```
2017-05-04T13:47:58.888875+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:47:58.723117+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:47:58.723117+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:47:58.888875+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:51:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:51:33.237737+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:51:33.212441+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 30333e7 by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:51:33.212441+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user innova-rd@cat-amania.com
2017-05-04T13:51:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-04T13:51:36.718804+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-05-04T13:51:41.387022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-04T13:51:41.387904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-04T13:51:41.372895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-04T13:51:41.246395+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.246409+00:00 app[web.1]: > innova-client@ start /app
2017-05-04T13:51:41.246410+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js
2017-05-04T13:51:41.246410+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.254190+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
2017-05-04T13:51:41.260595+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.271775+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-04T13:51:41.272071+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-05-04T13:51:41.272273+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.3
2017-05-04T13:51:41.272429+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-04T13:51:41.272604+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-05-04T13:51:41.272791+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-04T13:51:41.272960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-05-04T13:51:41.273140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-05-04T13:51:41.273296+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! innova-client@ start: `webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js`
2017-05-04T13:51:41.273666+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-05-04T13:51:41.273848+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-05-04T13:51:41.274051+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the innova-client@ start script 'webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js'.
2017-05-04T13:51:41.274199+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-04T13:51:41.274353+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the innova-client package,
2017-05-04T13:51:41.274469+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-04T13:51:41.274601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.274735+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js
2017-05-04T13:51:41.274895+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.275008+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs innova-client
2017-05-04T13:51:41.275144+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.275281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls innova-client
2017-05-04T13:51:41.275407+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-04T13:51:41.280628+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.280973+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-04T13:51:41.281167+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-04T13:51:43.507550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-05-04T13:51:46.187246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-04T13:51:46.170663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-04T13:51:46.080016+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.080035+00:00 app[web.1]: > innova-client@ start /app
2017-05-04T13:51:46.080036+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js
2017-05-04T13:51:46.080037+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.085844+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
2017-05-04T13:51:46.090229+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.098379+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.3
2017-05-04T13:51:46.097880+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-04T13:51:46.098161+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-05-04T13:51:46.098567+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-04T13:51:46.098738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099801+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-04T13:51:46.098883+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099017+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099270+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099402+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! innova-client@ start: `webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js`
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099497+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099715+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the innova-client@ start script 'webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js'.
2017-05-04T13:51:46.099918+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the innova-client package,
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100003+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-04T13:51:46.104341+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100170+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100261+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100340+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs innova-client
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100600+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls innova-client
2017-05-04T13:51:46.100763+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-04T13:51:46.104506+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-04T13:51:46.104590+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-04T13:51:47.506127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=socletechnique.herokuapp.com request_id=02ed8b61-fa43-417c-a5c7-64b510d4a2b8 fwd="77.154.192.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-04T13:51:47.864947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=socletechnique.herokuapp.com request_id=c9efb2df-46db-40e2-bc44-c4026a08ed5f fwd="77.154.192.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Do you know why it can't run on heroku ?

EDIT

I moved the dependencies in 'devDependencies' into 'dependencies' and it worked.
Now it still crashes because it can't find the 'react' library I use for my coding...
Here are the logs :

```
>heroku logs
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259390+00:00 app[web.1]:   [397] ./~/redux-persist/lib/defaults/asyncLocalStorage.js 3.73 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259391+00:00 app[web.1]:   [398] ./~/redux-persist/lib/utils/setImmediate.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259391+00:00 app[web.1]:   [399] ./~/redux-persist/lib/purgeStoredState.js 1.61 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259392+00:00 app[web.1]:   [400] ./~/json-stringify-safe/stringify.js 907 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259392+00:00 app[web.1]:   [401] ./~/redux-persist/lib/createTransform.js 769 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259392+00:00 app[web.1]:   [402] ./~/redux-persist/lib/getStoredState.js 3.41 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259393+00:00 app[web.1]:   [403] ./~/redux-persist/lib/persistStore.js 2.53 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259393+00:00 app[web.1]:   [404] ./src/components/App.tsx 514 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259394+00:00 app[web.1]:   [405] ./src/components/Header.tsx 906 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259394+00:00 app[web.1]:   [406] ./src/components/NavLink.tsx 588 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259395+00:00 app[web.1]:   [407] ./src/pages/accueil/index.tsx 206 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259395+00:00 app[web.1]:   [408] ./src/modules/cv/containers/CvListContainer.tsx 1.59 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259396+00:00 app[web.1]:   [409] ./src/modules/cv/components/CvList.tsx 366 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259396+00:00 app[web.1]:   [410] ./src/modules/cv/components/Cv.tsx 517 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259397+00:00 app[web.1]:   [411] ./src/pages/recupererCv/index.tsx 552 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259397+00:00 app[web.1]:   [412] ./src/modules/cv/containers/FormFindCvContainer.tsx 1.99 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259398+00:00 app[web.1]:   [413] ./src/modules/cv/components/FormFindCv.tsx 585 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259398+00:00 app[web.1]:   [414] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvRechercheContainer.tsx 2.14 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259399+00:00 app[web.1]:   [415] ./src/pages/ajouterCv/index.tsx 534 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259399+00:00 app[web.1]:   [416] ./src/modules/cv/containers/CreateCvContainer.tsx 2.03 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259400+00:00 app[web.1]:   [417] ./src/modules/cv/components/CreateCv.tsx 1.65 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259400+00:00 app[web.1]:   [418] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvAjoutContainer.tsx 2.01 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259403+00:00 app[web.1]:   [419] ./src/pages/modifierCv/index.tsx 230 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259403+00:00 app[web.1]:   [420] ./src/modules/cv/containers/ModifierCvRootContainer.tsx 1.7 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259404+00:00 app[web.1]:   [421] ./src/modules/cv/containers/ModifierCvContainer.tsx 2.68 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259404+00:00 app[web.1]:   [422] ./src/modules/cv/components/ModifierCv.tsx 1.8 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259405+00:00 app[web.1]:   [423] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvUpdateContainer.tsx 2.03 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259405+00:00 app[web.1]:   [424] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259406+00:00 app[web.1]:   [425] ./src/pages/detailCv/index.tsx 212 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259406+00:00 app[web.1]:   [426] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvContainer.tsx 467 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259409+00:00 app[web.1]:   [427] ./src/modules/cv/components/DetailCv.tsx 459 bytes {0} [built]
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259410+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259411+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259411+00:00 app[web.1]: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./pages/NotFound in /app/src
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259412+00:00 app[web.1]:  @ ./src/index.tsx 15:17-44
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259412+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259413+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/NavLink.tsx:2:31
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259414+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router'. '/app/node_modules/react-router/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259414+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259415+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:2:22
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259416+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dom'. '/app/node_modules/react-dom/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259416+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259417+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:3:67
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259417+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router'. '/app/node_modules/react-router/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259418+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259418+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:4:36
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259419+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-router-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259420+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259420+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:5:24
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259421+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259421+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259422+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:13:26
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259422+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS2307: Cannot find module './pages/NotFound'.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259423+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/actions/DetailCvAction.tsx:2:24
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259423+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259424+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259424+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259425+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/components/Cv.tsx:3:20
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259425+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router'. '/app/node_modules/react-router/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259426+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259426+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/CreateCvContainer.tsx:3:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259427+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259427+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259428+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/CvListContainer.tsx:2:30
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259429+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router'. '/app/node_modules/react-router/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259429+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259430+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/CvListContainer.tsx:3:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259431+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259432+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259432+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvAjoutContainer.tsx:2:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259433+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259434+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259435+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'lodash'. '/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259435+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259434+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvContainer.tsx:2:25
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259436+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvContainer.tsx:3:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259436+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259437+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259437+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvContainer.tsx:6:35
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259438+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router'. '/app/node_modules/react-router/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259438+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259439+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvContainer.tsx:14:81
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259440+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS2339: Property 'params' does not exist on type 'IProps'.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259440+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259440+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvRechercheContainer.tsx:2:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259441+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259442+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259442+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/DetailCvUpdateContainer.tsx:2:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259443+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259443+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259444+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/FormFindCvContainer.tsx:5:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259448+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259449+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259449+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/modules/cv/containers/ModifierCvContainer.tsx:7:23
2017-05-05T08:45:50.259450+00:00 app[web.1]:     TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-redux'. '/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2017-05-05T08:46:38.990271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-05-05T08:46:38.990271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-05-05T08:46:39.145493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-05-05T08:46:39.163148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-05T08:46:41.159604+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=socletechnique.herokuapp.com request_id=07a2a72d-1cd8-456c-905f-97bf66ae842b fwd="77.154.192.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-05T08:46:40.612403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=socletechnique.herokuapp.com request_id=49ac63e2-84a7-4299-a84b-08e0ae1e7f90 fwd="77.154.192.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

It says :

`webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.standalone.js`

Make sure that you have installed this module, in addition since you are trying to run it from the console, you might need to install it globally as well using the -g flag (`npm install -g package-name`)

Comment: definitely not the way to go.

Comment: I got it work but another error occured... i've edited the question to explain it

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

I don't know for sure what's causing the issue but you could call it from its path: `./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` or install it globally using the `-g` flag. This is likely to be user permission related.